# Google Play Games Services Publishing API is not responding

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client

I was using Google Play Games Services Publishing API for a long time, but currently it's not possible. It seems like something has broken down even though discovery.apis.list method returns 200 for this API (https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis/list?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamesConfiguration%22%7D) so it should work, but it's discoveryRestUrl https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gamesConfiguration/v1configuration/rest returns `Not Found`

I'm using gooogle-api-python-client==1.7.11 and service is build just like in official samples (https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/blob/master/publishing-sample/games-config.py).

Samples also doesn't work. The error I get is:

```
  File "...\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 234, in build
    "name: %s  version: %s" % (serviceName, version))
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: gamesConfiguration  version: v1configuration
```

It this service really unavailable anymore or am I doing something wrong?